# How To End Drop Down Mode for an Android Custom Spinner

Tags: android

I am creating a Spinner instance that I bind to my own custom adapter class (derived from BaseAdapter). In it, I create a bunch of custom "cell" LinearLayout-derived instances that I inflate from xml to be used for each item in the spinner.

Everything looks fine as expected, but whenever the items in "drop down" mode are clicked, the drop down dialog does not get dismissed.

I can trap the click notification inside my cell class, but what is the magic sauce I need to tell the spinner that an item was selected and that it should dismiss the drop down?

My cell class is inflated from the following xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/VIEW_LEAF" 
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          >

  <TextView android:id="@+id/STATIC_LEAF_NAME" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="3dip" 
            android:paddingTop="20dip" 
            android:paddingBottom="20dip" 
            android:textSize="22sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/black_enabled_grey_disabled"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

My cell class looks like so:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

// This class is responsible for rendering the data in the model.

public class DataCell extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener
{
  private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    public DataCell(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        m_context = context;

        final boolean attachToRoot = true;
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.data_cell, 
                this, attachToRoot);

    m_labelName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.STATIC_LEAF_NAME);
    m_labelName.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // Update the views with the data corresponding to selection index.
    // If dropDown is true, this view is to be displayed in a dropped down
    // list.
    public void display(int index, ViewGroup parent, Data data, boolean dropDown)
    {
      m_data = data;
        m_labelName.setText(data.getFriendlyName());

        setFocusable(true);
    }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view)
  {
    ViewParent parent = getParent();
    if(parent instanceof Spinner)
    {
      //((Spinner)parent).setSelection(2);// TODO something here?
    }
  }

  private TextView m_labelName = null;

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private Context m_context = null;

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private Data m_data = null;
}
```

Thanks!
swine

Comment: It should close automatically. It feels like the `Spinner` is not getting the events. What is in your "cells"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you were right about the cell stealing the clicks. But there was a very simple solution to all this, just not very obvious. All I had to do is make the TextView inside my DataCell not respond to clicks.

So I removed the m_labelName.onClickListener() call completely, and instead, at that location, put in the following code:

```
m_labelName.setClickable(false);
m_labelName.setFocusable(false);
m_labelName.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would delete the entire `DataCell` class, since it is doing you no good. If I had to guess, 99.9% of the uses of `Spinner` do not involve creating your own subclass of `LinearLayout`.

If there is more to this class than you elected to show, enough to make it worthwhile, then you should not be intercepting and consuming the click events. `Spinner` handles that automatically. If I had to guess, 99.999% of the uses of `Spinner` do not involve the contents of the dropdown list being involved in click events.

Comment: how else do you control the formatting of the items inside the spinner? the whole point of my cell class is to allow for extension later, like adding icons etc to each item in the spinner drop down. this is a common approach (componentization). if you know of a better way to do this, i'm all ears. thanks.

Comment: @swinefeaster: "how else do you control the formatting of the items inside the spinner?" -- simply pass the `SpinnerAdapter` the appropriate XML layout ID (e.g., `R.id.spinner_item`). "this is a common approach (componentization)." -- you don't "componentize" in Java, unless there is substantial business logic. GUI composition in Android is handled via layout XML resources.

Comment: Yes I'm using my own adapter, because it needs to connect to a custom data model that is populated from my backend subsystem.